# parse a json in a column of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe(df) with the following structure.

**Input:**

```
ID data
1 {"customerinfo":{zip:834247}}
2 {"score":535,"customerinfo":{zip:834244}}
```

I wanted to parse the json data as a new columns, such as to get the following:

**Expected Output:**

```
ID zipcode     score
1  834247      NULL
2  834244      535
```

**Original Solution:**

```
df['bureauScore'] = df['data'].transform(lambda x: json.loads(x)['score'])
df['zipcode'] = df['data'].transform(lambda x: json.loads(x)['customerinfo']['zipcode'])
```

**Problem:**

If a field is missing the code fails, thus I tired to add a get function as shown below, but that fails here with the following error

**Attempted Solution**

```
df['bureauScore'] = df['data'].transform(lambda x: json.loads(get(x))['score'])
```

**Error:**

```
NameError: name 'get' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: I know about json_normalize but I have multiple fields, thus wanted this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) - it return `NaN` if no match:

```
#convert to jsons only once to helper Series s
s = df['data'].transform(json.loads)

df['bureauScore'] = s.str.get('score')
df['zipcode'] = s.str.get('customerinfo').str.get('zip')

print (df)

   ID                                         data  bureauScore  zipcode
0   1              {"customerinfo":{"zip":834247}}          NaN   834247
1   2  {"score":535,"customerinfo":{"zip":834244}}        535.0   834244
```